# Postgres create POSTGIS extension error with CentOS 6

Tags: postgresql, centos, postgis

I am running `PostgreSQL 9.3` with `Postgis 2.0` on `CentOS 6.3`.

I installed PostgreSQL and PostGIS according to this instructions:
http://trac.osgeo.org/postgis/wiki/UsersWikiPostGIS21CentOS6pgdg

When trying to create `Postgis` extension

```
Create Extension Postgis;
```

I get the following error,

```
ERROR:  could not load library "/usr/pgsql-9.3/lib/rtpostgis-2.1.so": libhdf5.so.6: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

May I know how to install the POSTGIS extension successfully?

Comment: Recently I have successfully installed postgresql-9.3, postgis2.1 on CentOS 6.5 x64 without any problem. FYI.

Answer (score 2):

I have CentOs 6.5 and did this:

1) Install following packages

- hdf5-1.8.11-42.1.x86_64.rpm
- json-c-0.10-2.1.x86_64.rpm
- libhdf5-8-1.8.11-42.1.x86_64.rpm
- libhdf5_hl8-1.8.11-42.1.x86_64.rpm

I don't know if I can link files directly here, so look for those files at rpm.pbone.net, download CentOS 6 version.

2) As Postgis requires version hdf5 version 6, you have to execute this commands as root (# is prompt)

```
# cd /usr/lib64
# ln -s libhdf5_hl.so.8 libhdf5_hl.so.6
# ln -s libhdf5.so.8 libhdf5.so.6
```

PS Don't forget to install postgresql contrib package, as Postgis requires fuzzystrmatch extension for some modules.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried installing the package that contains libhdf5 and then tried running again the create extension command? Apparently postgis is linked to that package which is not present on your system.

Comment: may I know the package name contains libhdf5 in centos repo?